# Reduce bots priority with mod_rails (passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, bots, thin

With my current thin setup I can reduce bots priority redirecting them to one specific server instance with a lower priority:

```
# put some bots in one proxy port
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?:Googlebot|bing|Mediapartners|Adsbot|Feedfetcher) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://localhost:50003%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
# deny other bots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baidu [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F] 
# deny empty user-agent
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
```

And then lowering its priority by running

```
renice 20 `cat tmp/pids/thin.50003.pid`
```

But I have no idea on how to do that with Passenger, since it doesn't use a balancer. This is pretty much necessary for my server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Phusion Passenger's [Standalone mode](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html) to achieve this. Start a Standalone server with 1 process at low priority:

```
nice passenger start -p 50003 -e production
```

Now Passenger will be listening on port 50003, and you can continue using your existing rewrite rules and proxy rules.